# NoReverseMatch at

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I've got this issue trying to `redirect` after submitting a form:

> NoReverseMatch at /app_blog/blog/1/blog_update/
>
> Reverse for 'blog_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app_blog/blog/(?P[0-9]+)/blog_detail/$']

***views.py:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
# from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib import messages

from app_users.decorators import unauthenticated_user, allowed_users

from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import BlogUpdateForm

@login_required(login_url='app_users:login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['admin', 'staff', 'users'])
def blog(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.all()
    context = {'title': 'Blog', 'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'app_blog/blog.html', context)

def blog_detail(request, pk):
    user_post = BlogPost.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'title': 'Blog', 'user_post': user_post}
    return render(request, 'app_blog/blog_detail.html', context)

def blog_user_detail(request, pk):
    user_detail = BlogPost.objects.get(id=pk)
    user_type = user_detail.author.groups.all()[0].name.capitalize()
    context = {'title': 'Blog', 'user_detail': user_detail, 'user_type': user_type}
    return render(request, 'app_blog/blog_user_detail.html', context)

def blog_update(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        blog_update = BlogUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=BlogPost.objects.get(id=pk))
        if blog_update.is_valid():
            blog_update.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your blog-post has been updated!')
            return redirect('app_blog:blog_detail')
    else:
        blog_update = BlogUpdateForm(instance=BlogPost.objects.get(id=pk))
    context = {'title': 'Blog', 'blog_update': blog_update}
    return render(request, 'app_blog/blog_update.html', context)
```

***urls.py:***

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

app_name = 'app_blog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', blog, name='blog'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/blog_detail/', blog_detail, name='blog_detail'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/user_details/', blog_user_detail, name='blog_user_detail'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/blog_update/', blog_update, name='blog_update'),
]
```

***models.py:***

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

***blog_detail.html:***

```html
{% extends 'app_t35/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

<br>
    <div class="container">
        <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-image" src="{{ user_post.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="Image Missing!">
            <div class="card-body media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'app_blog:blog_user_detail' user_post.id %}">{{ user_post.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ user_post.date_posted|date:"d F, Y" }}</small>
                    {% if user_post.author == request.user %}
                        <div>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'app_blog:blog_update' user_post.id %}">Update</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <h2 class="article-title">{{ user_post.title }}</h2>
                <p class="article-content">{{ user_post.content|safe }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
<br>

{% endblock %}
```

***blog_update.html:***

```html
{% extends 'app_t35/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

<br>
<div class="card card-body container">
    <div class="card-deck">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <h5 style="text-align: left;">{{ user.username }}:</h5>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">If you wish to update your blog-post:</legend>
                    {{ blog_update|crispy }}
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info  btn-sm btn-block" style="width: 150px; align-self: center;" type="submit">Update Details</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, got it, days later...

```
 def blog_update(request, pk):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         blog_update = BlogUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=BlogPost.objects.get(id=pk))
         if blog_update.is_valid():
             blog_update.save()
             messages.success(request, 'Your blog-post has been updated!')
             return redirect('app_blog:blog_detail')
```

the `return redirect(...` needs to have the `pk` just as an argument, as the `redirect` itself takes `*args` & `**kwargs` so the complete line is:

```
return redirect('app_blog:blog_detail', pk)
```

Answer (score 1):

In blog update view -You did not pass the id of the blog post in redirect .
use HttpResponseRedirect and pass the id of the blog where you want to redirect.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_blog:blog_detail',args=[pk]))
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work(btw, should be ...args=...)
I now get:
`Reverse for 'blog_detail' with arguments '(<BlogPost: AnotherBlogPost>,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app_blog/blog/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/blog_detail/$']`

Comment: Sorry this is my mistake.Just pass pk as aargument .I passed a object insted.Hope this time will work.  The main purpose is send the blog id through the args

Comment: Or you can also do it this way using kwargs 

```return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_blog:blog_detail',kwargs={'pk': pk }))```

Comment: yeah, that's what i've always thought but can't get that pk passed without getting back an error like the above...

Comment: as per my reply above... it's a Not.

Answer (score 0):

use `reverse` function from django shortcuts

Comment: used `return redirect(reverse(` as well, doesn't work.

Comment: `return reverse(viewname=blog_detail, args=[pk], current_app='app_blog')`
or 
`return reverse(viewname=blog_detail, kwargs={'id':pk}, current_app='app_blog')`

gets me this:
`NoReverseMatch at /app_blog/blog/1/blog_update/

Reverse for 'app_blog.views.blog_detail' not found. 'app_blog.views.blog_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`